# Two routers in one house, want one to stand alone from the other , (the other isn't mine, it's a roommates)

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have a linksys router at home and I want it to stand alone ( meaning I don't want mine connected to my roommates router to get internet). Mine is plugged in the wall in a bedroom but it says I'm connected through their router but I don't know how to seperate them since we are both plugged into the same house, and what makes theirs the host instead of the other way around? Is it because theirs is in a optimal location or because they also have a modem and I don't? Both of our routers are wireless and my printer won't connect to my router but will connect to there's because I think it thinks mine is just a branch of the internet connection instead of the root . Anyone know how to make my router stand alone ?

Comment: You have your own ISP, or is it a shared service?

Comment: Your question is based on a number of false assumptions. You would do better to tell us more information about how things are set up and avoid describing things using conclusions rather than observations. (For example, "I think it thinks mine is just a branch of the internet connection instead of the root" makes no sense.

Comment: To over-simplify... a router finds a route to a destination - a modem makes a connection to the internet. You appear to have 'borrowed' someone else's modem & want it to behave as if it was your own (as well as theirs). It won't do that, in the way you expect.

Answer (score 1):

If your modem has a built-in switch, just connect each of the routers to a port on the modem.  You will need to specify a separate subnet for your router, i.e. if the modem or other router is using 192.168.1.x, you need to use 192.168.2.x and make sure you gateway to the modem subnet.

Comment: It's not necessary to have different network addresses on each router's private side, if his devices do not intend to talk to his roommate's devices.  Having each router's WiFi set at least 5 channels apart from each other is a must, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could connect a switch to your modem, and then connect the WAN ports of your router and your roommate's router to different ports on the switch.

However, for this to work, your ISP would need to allow customers to get multiple IPs. Most residential ISPs don't allow this, and those that do may require you to pay extra for the feature. If you only have one IP, then you can only connect one router to the modem. If you want to have your own router, you'll need to daisy-chain them.